# How to take control of existing terminal programs via ssh (cmus)

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-mint, cmus

So I have a terminal with cmus running on my main PC at my desk.

I want to ssh to this main PC from my laptop and "take control" of cmus remotely, so that i can adjust volume, pause and play, choose the song, etc.

Note: I don't want to stream music via ssh. I just want to take control of an existing cmus session via ssh.

both machines are running linux mint.

My question is different to other questions already asked because I want to take control of an *existing* cmus process, rather than spawning a new one.

Comment: And the simplest way to **avoid** having to "take control" is to use `screen` or `tmux`, start `cmus` inside a session, and then attach to the session when you `ssh` in.

Comment: @dirkt I have been searching long and hard, as well as experimenting and playing around in my terminals, but I can't work out how to do this. Can you link me to something which explains how to "attach to an existing screen session over ssh?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your main PC:

```
$ tmux
```

(Tmux window opens)

```
$ cmus
```

From your laptop:

```
$ ssh main-pc
$ tmux ls
$ tmux attach
```

First commands shows you the sessions, second command attaches (as there is only one session).

Comment: thanks so much for this. I ended up working out how to do the equivalent using GNU screen, but couldn't have found the solution without your help!